# rosjava compilation error

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while compiling recent rosjava_core library following error was encountered.

> > Building > :apache_xmlrpc_server:compileJava >
> > Resolving dependencies
> > ':apache_xmlrpc_server:compil:apache_xmlrpc_server:compileJava
> > Note: Some input files use unchecked
> > or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile
> > with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> > :apache_xmlrpc_server:processResources
> > UP-TO-DATE
> > :apache_xmlrpc_server:classes
> > :apache_xmlrpc_server:jar
> > :apache_xmlrpc_server:install
> > :rosjava_bootstrap:compileJava
> > UP-TO-DATE
> > :rosjava_bootstrap:processResources
> > UP-TO-DATE :rosjava_bootstrap:classes
> > UP-TO-DATE :rosjava_bootstrap:jar
> > :rosjava_messages:generateSources
> > :rosjava_messages:compileJava
> > /home/pragyan/Techiome/rosjava_core/rosjava_messages/build/generated-src/test_rosjava_jni/TestDataTypes.java:52:
> > getByte() is already defined in
> > test_rosjava_jni.TestDataTypes
> > std_msgs.Byte getByte();
> > ^ /home/pragyan/Techiome/rosjava_core/rosjava_messages/build/generated-src/test_rosjava_jni/TestDataTypes.java:54:
> > getByteV() is already defined in
> > test_rosjava_jni.TestDataTypes
> > java.util.List<std_msgs.Byte>
> > getByteV();
> > ^ 2 errors
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an
> exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':rosjava_messages:compileJava'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log
>   output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 57.017 secs

any clue how to resolve this?
I m using ubuntu 10.10 over electric distribution of ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37342/rosjava-compilation-error/) by [pntripathi9417](https://answers.ros.org/users/1369/pntripathi9417/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-06-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://answers.ros.org/question/37440/did-rosjava-break-at-most-recent-push/

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0